# import mysql data to solr

Tags: mysql, solr

I'm new to solr and I'm trying to import simple data from mysql, but examples which I found are not working for me.
In `solrconfig.xml` I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <config>
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport"  class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler> 
more stuffs..
```

and in `data-config.xml`

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource 
    type="JdbcDataSource" 
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" 
    user="root" 
    password=""/>

 <document> 
   <entity name="name"  
     query="SELECT * FROM name">
    </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

If I try to make a new collection, mysqlCol for example, I receive this error

`Error CREATEing SolrCore 'mysqlCol': Unable to create core: mysqlCol Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler`

OR

if I try to put these lines of code in the existing collection1 and run from cmd with `java -jar start.jar` the error is

`2758 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  û U
nable to create core: collection1`

In \lib\ I've put the driver for mysql `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar`, but still nothing. I'm using Windows 7. Any help will be highly appreciated.

The whole stack:

```
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xm
  pcore-5.1.2.jar' to classloader
  1723 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/extraction/lib/xz
  -1.4.jar' to classloader
  1725 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/dist/solr-cell-4.9.0.jar'
   to classloader
  1726 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/at
  tributes-binder-1.2.1.jar' to classloader
  1727 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/ca
  rrot2-mini-3.9.0.jar' to classloader
  1729 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/hp
  pc-0.5.2.jar' to classloader
  1730 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/ja
  ckson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar' to classloader
  1731 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/ja
  ckson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar' to classloader
  1731 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/ma
  hout-collections-1.0.jar' to classloader
  1733 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/ma
  hout-math-0.6.jar' to classloader
  1733 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/clustering/lib/si
  mple-xml-2.7.jar' to classloader
  1735 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/dist/solr-clustering-4.9.
  0.jar' to classloader
  1736 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/langid/lib/jsonic
  -1.2.7.jar' to classloader
  1736 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/langid/lib/langde
  tect-1.1-20120112.jar' to classloader
  1737 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/dist/solr-langid-4.9.0.ja
  r' to classloader
  1738 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/velocity/lib/comm
  ons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar' to classloader
  1739 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/velocity/lib/comm
  ons-collections-3.2.1.jar' to classloader
  1739 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velo
  city-1.7.jar' to classloader
  1740 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/contrib/velocity/lib/velo
  city-tools-2.0.jar' to classloader
  1741 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader
    û Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Bulgaria12/sites/solr-4.9.0/dist/solr-velocity-4.9.0.
  jar' to classloader
  1799 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexConfig
   û IndexWriter infoStream solr logging is enabled
  1805 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig  û Usin
  g Lucene MatchVersion: LUCENE_4_9
  1894 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.Config  û Loaded S
  olrConfig: solrconfig.xml
  1900 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  û R
  eading Solr Schema from schema.xml
  1931 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  û [
  collection1] Schema name=example
  2392 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  û u
  nique key field: id
  2404 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.rest.RestManager  û Reg
  istered ManagedResource impl org.apache.solr.rest.schema.analysis.ManagedWordSet
  Resource for path /schema/analysis/stopwords/english
  2405 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.rest.RestManager  û Reg
  istered ManagedResource impl org.apache.solr.rest.schema.analysis.ManagedSynonym
  FilterFactory$SynonymManager for path /schema/analysis/synonyms/english
  2467 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.FileExchangeRate
  Provider  û Reloading exchange rates from file currency.xml
  2472 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.FileExchangeRate
  Provider  û Reloading exchange rates from file currency.xml
  2526 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  û C
  reating SolrCore 'collection1' using configuration from instancedir C:\Users\Bul
  garia12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\collection1\
  2540 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û solr.N
  RTCachingDirectoryFactory
  2548 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û [colle
  ction1] Opening new SolrCore at C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\sol
  r\collection1\, dataDir=C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\collec
  tion1\data\
  2550 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.JmxMonitoredMap  û
   No JMX servers found, not exposing Solr information with JMX.
  2554 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û [colle
  ction1] Added SolrEventListener for newSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySende
  rListener{queries=[]}
  2554 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û [colle
  ction1] Added SolrEventListener for firstSearcher: org.apache.solr.core.QuerySen
  derListener{queries=[{q=static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml}]}
  2566 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFa
  ctory  û return new directory for C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\s
  olr\collection1\data
  2567 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û New in
  dex directory detected: old=null new=C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\exampl
  e\solr\collection1\data\index/
  2568 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFa
  ctory  û return new directory for C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\s
  olr\collection1\data\index
  2580 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û create
  d json: solr.JSONResponseWriter
  2581 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û adding
   lazy queryResponseWriter: solr.VelocityResponseWriter
  2582 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û create
  d velocity: solr.VelocityResponseWriter
  2586 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û create
  d xslt: solr.XSLTResponseWriter
  2586 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.response.XSLTResponseWr
  iter  û xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds=5
  2662 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û no upd
  ateRequestProcessorChain defined as default, creating implicit default
  2670 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /select: solr.SearchHandler
  2671 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /query: solr.SearchHandler
  2673 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /get: solr.RealTimeGetHandler
  2673 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /browse: solr.SearchHandler
  2677 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /update: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
  2677 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /update/json: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
  2678 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /update/csv: solr.UpdateRequestHandler
  2679 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
  2680 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /update/extract: solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler
  2681 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
  2681 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /analysis/field: solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler
  2682 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
  2682 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /analysis/document: solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler
  2684 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /admin/: solr.admin.AdminHandlers
  2686 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /admin/ping: solr.PingRequestHandler
  2687 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /debug/dump: solr.DumpRequestHandler
  2696 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /replication: solr.ReplicationHandler
  2696 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
  2696 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /spell: solr.SearchHandler
  2696 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
  2697 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /suggest: solr.SearchHandler
  2697 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
  2697 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /tvrh: solr.SearchHandler
  2697 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
  2698 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /terms: solr.SearchHandler
  2698 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   adding lazy requestHandler: solr.SearchHandler
  2698 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers  û
   created /elevate: solr.SearchHandler
  2705 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û [colle
  ction1]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@1a9281f
  2706 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.SolrCoreState  û
   Closing SolrCoreState
  2706 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreS
  tate  û SolrCoreState ref count has reached 0 - closing IndexWriter
  2706 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û [colle
  ction1] Closing main searcher on request.
  2707 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFa
  ctory  û Closing NRTCachingDirectoryFactory - 2 directories currently being trac
  ked
  2707 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFa
  ctory  û looking to close C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\coll
  ection1\data\index [CachedDir<<refCount=0;path=C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.
  9.0\example\solr\collection1\data\index;done=false>>]
  2708 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFa
  ctory  û Closing directory: C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\co
  llection1\data\index
  2708 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFa
  ctory  û looking to close C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\coll
  ection1\data [CachedDir<<refCount=0;path=C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\ex
  ample\solr\collection1\data;done=false>>]
  2709 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFa
  ctory  û Closing directory: C:\Users\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example\solr\co
  llection1\data
  2710 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  û U
  nable to create core: collection1
  org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:868)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:643)
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:556)
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:261)
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:253)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
          at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHa
  ndlers.java:167)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:787)
          ... 10 more
  Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache
  .solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
  java:490)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
  java:421)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:540)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:613)      

          at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHa
  ndlers.java:153)
          ... 11 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.
  DataImportHandler
          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
          at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
  java:474)
          ... 15 more
  2714 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  û n
  ull:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: collection1
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:
  911)
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:568)
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:261)
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:253)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:868)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:643)
          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:556)
          ... 8 more
  Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
          at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHa
  ndlers.java:167)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:787)
          ... 10 more
  Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache
  .solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
  java:490)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
  java:421)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:540)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:613)      

          at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHa
  ndlers.java:153)
          ... 11 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.
  DataImportHandler
          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
          at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.
  java:474)
          ... 15 more      

  2717 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  û user.dir=C:\User
  s\Bulgaria12\sites\solr-4.9.0\example
  2717 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  û SolrDispatchFilt
  er.init() done
  2735 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  û Started SocketCo
  nnector@0.0.0.0:8983
```

Comment: could you please print the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrongly set path to libraries:
check solrconfig.xml
there should be:

`<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />`
 .....
`

And it should point to directory where this library is located - i had to change it up one directory form default installation, yours may be different, you may put there absolute path in beginning to see it working.

Comment: Thank you, I though that this could be the reason, but I've made installation in another pc with the same version and OS, and everything was just fine.. However, you answer fix the issue here.